# CodeIgniter Select column into variable give error

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

I have this code using a transaction on codeigniter

```
$this->db->trans_begin();

$this->db->query("SET @clientID = {$client_id}, @amount = {$amount}, @gameID = {$game_id}, @tableID = {$table_id}, @tableName = '{$table_name}', @usedBalanceID = NULL");

$this->db->query("SELECT availableBalance INTO @availableBalance FROM client WHERE clientID = @clientID");
```

the SELECT availableBalance INTO @availableBalance
gives me an error saying

```
Severity: Warning  --> mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result;
system\database\drivers\mysqli\mysqli_result.php 37
```

but using returns no error

```
$this->db->query("SELECT @availableBalance := availableBalance FROM client WHERE clientID = @clientID");
```

can anyone explain why i get this error on codeigniter

but when using the code on laravel

```
SELECT availableBalance INTO @availableBalance FROM client WHERE clientID = @clientID
```

working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$this->db->trans_begin();

$this->db->query("SET @clientID = {$client_id}, @amount = {$amount}, @gameID = {$game_id}, @tableID = {$table_id}, @tableName = '{$table_name}', @usedBalanceID = NULL");

$this->db->query("SELECT availableBalance INTO @availableBalance FROM client WHERE clientID = @clientID");
```

- I just noticed that @availableBalance is no where to find, so basically it will throw an error.

"SELECT @availableBalance := availableBalance FROM client WHERE clientID = @clientID";

- This is running okay because @availableBalance is being used like an storage and being defined/set.

I had created a sample sql script to explain my answer. Hope it helps! Cheers!

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/35b47/7)

Answer (score 0):

The **SELECT INTO** statement [selects data from one table and inserts it into a new table](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp). You are getting the error because the SELECT part of your query `$this->db->query("SELECT availableBalance INTO @availableBalance FROM client WHERE clientID = @clientID");` is returning `false` and therefore there is no value that can be inserted in the table `@availableBalance`.

Please check the `client` table because SQL isn't able to find any value in the column `availableBalance` against `clientID = @clientID`.

Comment: but the query runs smooth if do it on the mysql workbench/console and returns data, but when using it to codeigniter returns errors, but when using the query using the 
":=" returns no error

Comment: Are you sure CodeIgniter is using the same db that you are using in the mysql workbench/console? Please double check!

Comment: yes,
why the SELECT INTO query is having error to code igniter
but the SELECT := is ok to code igniter. does it have to do with the query builder of code igniter?